# How to redirect after get data from post method

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a `post method to  servlet`,so servlet return a web page after forwarding a request to another page
 `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/AnotherServlet").forward(request, response);`
so i can't redirect directly `window.location ="/Anotherservlet"` 
 i tried many solution: passing parameters with links and it is working but i'would a better one
i tried `var w = window.open();   w.document.write(data);` and it is working but the url of the page still my home page and the page still loading even the page is downloaded from server(all function with ready statement not working) so when i click in button with href="#" it redirect me to home page because as i said before my URL=/ not =/anotherservlet
i don't like get method to do that or cookies for that i search for other solution thanks for help
this is my servlet :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    String name= request.getParameter("name");
    String pass=request.getParameter("pass");

     if (name.equals("a")&&pass.equals("0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661"))
    {
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/BookListServlet").forward(request, response);
    }
    else 
    {
     response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("error");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

this is my BookListServlet:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    books= new bookiml().get_books();   
    String name= request.getParameter("name");
    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

request.setAttribute("books", books);
request.setAttribute("userip", ipAddress);
request.setAttribute("user", name);
request.setAttribute("title", "Book listing");

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/META-INF/pages/book-list.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

i wan't to get the page from servlet after check login authentication , but not without passing parameters in link like that:`

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'identification',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:{pass:$hash,name:$name},
                    timeout: 1000,
                    success: function(data){
                     var target = document.getElementById('spinner');
                                    spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
                                    $('#spinner').fadeIn();

                                    if (data=='error')
                                    {
                                    $("#messages").html(" Check your username and password.");
                                    $('#name').css('border-color','#B94A48');
                                    $('#pass').css('border-color','#B94A48');
                                    $('#spinner').fadeOut();
                                    }

                                    else 

                                        {
                                        $("#messages").html("");


            $('#spinner').fadeOut();
                                    window.location ="/BookListServlet?name="+$name;
                                    }


                }
            });`
```

Comment: I'm sorry about it, but I fully fail to understand your question. Could you please try to re-edit the question, reconstruct the question in short, simple sentences of what you wanna achieve? Not too verbose please. It could be great if you also add your code.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you just want to redirect using `servlet`?

```
response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://splinky.com/");
```

Comment: and what about this getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/META-INF/pages/book-list.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: i cant use that because i don't need a static page a need it after forwarding a request

Comment: @Splinky Oh, I got it. If you need to forward a client's request to some other resource, you should use `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forwar‌​d(req, res);` Good example is here: http://www.servletworld.com/examples/servlet-forward.html

Comment: it is the some in my code ,without Jquery all is ok but when iuse jquery ican't manipulate the response from server

Answer (score 0):

You can put the url in the ajax response where you want to redirct in case of success:

example js response:

```
{ status: 'ok', redirect: '/example' }
```

And redirect with js on the client side.

Client side code:

```
$("form.ajaxForm").submit( function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        form.ajaxSubmit({
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if( data.redirect != "" ) {
                    window.location = data.redirect;
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

You have to use the jQuery form plugin to this to work. See: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started